# Python - How to convert Unicode code point to the character

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to convert english character into Star Wars Aurebesh characters.
I found the unicode code assignment for Aurebesh characters here: http://www.kreativekorp.com/ucsur/charts/aurebesh.htm

So with code point such as "U+E890", can I print out the Aurebesh character in python?

Comment: Try simply using: `print u'\ue890'`

Answer (score 1):

`print('\ue890')` will do the job.

Comment: It cannot print out the star wars character, but only an empty square...

Comment: You have to display it in a font that supports Aurebesh: http://www.fontspace.com/category/aurebesh

Comment: Do you know how to add this type of font in IPython? I downloaded the font but only work in my PowerPoint...

Answer (score 0):

In python3 you can do it by using escape char:
`print('\ue890')`

**EDIT:
Adding this to the answer as it involved a small discussion in the comments.**

In python2.7 you need to add extra u in front of the string to turn it into unicode string (courtesy of Matt Clark):
`print u'\ue890'`

Comment: You need to first define the whole string as unicode: `print(u'\ue890')`

Comment: You no longer have to do that in python 3.

Comment: python 3 gives identical results for `print(u'\ue890')` and `print('\ue890')` @MattClark

Comment: Huh, does it? Okay. 2.7 needs the prepended `u`.

Comment: python3 makes your pythonic life much easier! @MattClark

Comment: It cannot print out the star wars character, but only an empty square...

Comment: it all depends on whether your system font can display the character. Square is usually displayed when the font does not have the character in question.